# How can I handle different request url in same machine?

Tags: node.js, linux, docker, nginx

Below is my scenario..

I have three test sites which is beta.com, qa.com and alpha.com
However, I want to put these three under same linux system with docker.

How can I do that?

Is to use like Nginx to handle the request?What kind of keyword I can do the search on google?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: create a docker-compose with all 3 containers + 1 nginx container. Only the nginx should map a port to localhost (eg: 80:80 or 443:443 what suites you better). Containers don't need to map any port. Your nginx.conf you can find a lot of documentation. Important is to redirect the traffic to http://container_name:internal_port. Give it a try and if it doesn't work drop a comment and I can help.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/de/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/

Comment: https://medium.com/@joatmon08/using-containers-to-learn-nginx-reverse-proxy-6be8ac75a757